# Vue-Router error: "Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm getting the error below by trying to compile this [VueJS demo project](https://github.com/academind/yt-devmeetup-vue-firebase/tree/20-split-modules).
I update NPM to the latest stable version and all of the apps dependencies but the error remains.

As soon as I remove `vue-router` from `index.js` and `main.js` the error is gone.
This is the error message:

```
> ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-0a5cdd23"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Meetup/Meetups.vue Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (122:82)
> 
> 
> at Parser.pp$4.raise
> (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:2610:13)
>     at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:637:8)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:2094:10)
>     at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:4372:24)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1955:19)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1932:17)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1893:41)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1893:24)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1876:90)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1857:19)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1832:19)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:2139:30)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:2061:41)
>     at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:4372:24)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1955:19)
>     at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/tom/Desktop/DevMeetup/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:1932:17)
> @ ./src/components/Meetup/Meetups.vue 5:2-186  @ ./src/router/index.js
> @ ./src/main.js  @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

How to fix it? Any ideas are appreciated.
**Edit**: I tried `npm install` again and got a message about **url-loader** being vulnerable. I got suggested to `run npm install --save-dev url-loader@1.0.1` to fix it. The error remains but could this the root of the cause?

Comment: Did you try to update your node version?

Comment: Yes, I updated to the latest stable NodeJS release

Comment: The problem (probably a syntax error) is in the `Meetups.vue` component - take a deeper look at your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the error, compile finish successfully. Do you tried to clone again your repo? 
 I use 
npm: 6.0.1
node: v8.11.1

[image]